# adding keyup event with space for backbone

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, marionette

I would like to add an event listener whenever user clicks space (keyCode: 32)

how can I do it?
right know my event is triggered on every keyup() but I would like to limit it to space.

```
  class New.Editor extends App.Views.ItemView
    template: "document/new/_editor"

    triggers:
      "keyup" : "document:save"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like below should work:

```
triggers:
  "keyup" : saveFunction,


saveFunction = function(e){
    if (e.keyCode ==32) {
        document:save;
    }

}
```

Normal jQuery :

```
$("#test").keyup(function(e) {
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if (code==32) {
        //Your functions
    }   

});
```

Hope you get the idea..